# Error with GET request scraping coches.net

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have a problem because when I make the GET request to the website, it returns another HTML that is not that of the website, an HTML of an error page, so I cannot access the information about the cars. I have different headers so that the page does not detect anything strange, but it still detects that I am a bot.

```
desktop_agents = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'']

headers = {'User-Agent': random.choice(desktop_agents)}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(response.text)
```

With this code i do the request and returns me the html error page.

Comment: Hi, please include your code so we can more easily understand what goes wrong.

Comment: please include the code in your question, not in ther comment section, as it is part of your question, also you can do better markup inside questions compared to comments.

Comment: Also what kind of error page is it? a 404 page?

Comment: It returns an HTML error page that prevents me from accessing the HTML of the Coches.net main page. It does not give error 404, the status code is 200.

Comment: What is the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple parameters to your headers seems to work. However, after a few requests the website detects the botting again:

```
url = "https://www.coches.net/"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.54",
           "Accept-Encoding": "some nonsense"} # some nonsense can be anything
for i in range(10):
    print(f"try {i}":)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features = "html.parser")
    print(soup.find("title")) #print html title to see what page you are getting
```

Will output:

```
try 0:
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 1:
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 2:
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 3:
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 4:
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 5:
<title>Ups! Parece que algo no va bien...</title>
try 6:
<title>Ups! Parece que algo no va bien...</title>
try 7:
<title>Ups! Parece que algo no va bien...</title>
try 8:
<title>Ups! Parece que algo no va bien...</title>
try 9:
<title>Ups! Parece que algo no va bien...</title>
```

Meaning that after 5 tries, you are getting blocked. A simple work-around would be to select a random value and assign it in your headers.

```
for i in range(10):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.54",
               "Accept-Encoding": str(random.randint(1,10000000))}
    print(f"try {i}")
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features = "html.parser")
    print(soup.find("title"))
```

Outputs:

```
try 0
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 1
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 2
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 3
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 4
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 5
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 6
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 7
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 8
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
try 9
<title data-reactroot="" data-rh="">Coches.net: Coches nuevos, coches de ocasión, seminuevos, Km0</title>
```